# Setting cultureInfo for an async delegate

Tags: c#, .net, localization, delegates

Being new to C#, I am facing some issues in understanding the delegates and how culture flows in there.

I have a code snippet which looks similar to this:

```
await DoSomething(param1, param2, 
   async() = {
       result = someotherfunc(someinput);
   });
```

Now, I need to return results based on the user's Locale and for this I need to set the cultureInfo for the running thread (which can be set by setting the appropriate culture to `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`)

But, what I am not sure is where to set this `CurrentCulture` variable? Should it be inside the delegate's definition ?

Moreover, I don't know whether there will be a new thread when this delegate gets executed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thread have own culture, which if not defined explicitly derived from the system culture.

For having same culture over all threads you can use [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx) to set default culture for all threads.

If you need different culture for different delegates, then change `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in the same method where you showing/printing values out.

Comment: Can I simply set culture inside the async delegate body?

Comment: You can if creating of formatted value happened there

Comment: This solution for .NET 4.5+. On .NET 3.5, can I set default culture?

Comment: @okud, `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` should work in .NET 3.5

Comment: @Fabio I set only CurrentUICulture, not CurrentCulture. I got the reason why CurrentUICulture is not applied: CurrentCulture is for not UI Culture, and the delegates (BeginInvoke) use CurrentCulture because they are not for UI Culture. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Oops. Not applied about BeginInvoke on .NET 3.5 even if I was set CurrentCulture.